# How to perform operation within an index value in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict and I want to multiply the value in index position 2 by 2

```
val = {'paris': [200, 20, 200],
 'London': [250, 30, 120],
 'Dubai': [370, 15, 80],
 'Mumbai': [450, 10, 70]}
```

like `20*2,30*2` and so on

Expected result:

```
 val = {'paris': [200, 40, 200],
     'London': [250, 60, 120],
     'Dubai': [370, 30, 80],
     'Mumbai': [450, 20, 70]}
```

Comment: Well, OK, and what is your problem exactly? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I want to multiply the all the integers in the center of the list by 2

Comment: @DimkpaSimon And have you tried anything to do it? Do you know how to access the second element of a list? You simply do `myList[1]`. Then you can multiply by doing `myList[1] = myList[1] * 2`. Then you can use a for loop to go through all the lists in the dictionary. Have you tried this?

Comment: You already said that in your question, and as it stands, it's just "Write this code for me", which is not what SO is about; If you have met a **specific** problem trying to do that, please explain it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
for k, v in val.items():
    v[1] *= 2
```

Comment: `items`->`items()`

Comment: or `for v in val.values():`

Comment: It might be helpful to include some explanation of *why* this works, as OP may be a beginner and not know about operators like `*=`, or using tuples when iterating etc

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
val = {'paris': [200, 20, 200],
   'London': [250, 30, 120],
   'Dubai': [370, 15, 80],
   'Mumbai': [450, 10, 70]}

for city in val:
    val[city][1] = val[city][1]*2
    
print(val)

{'paris': [200, 40, 200], 'London': [250, 60, 120], 'Dubai': [370, 30, 80], 'Mumbai': [450, 20, 70]}
```